# Making http requests from heroku

Tags: node.js, http, heroku

Running locally this code works, make a request to the server and download the file. I want to, now run this code on heroku, but when I tried to push and run the code, dont work properly. How I make http requets from an app on heroku?

```
const optionsRequest = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
}
}
 https.get('https://v16-web-newkey.tiktokcdn.com/bd5e2f7686233fa58e4e2b9beaec57f8/5f7cfb78/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037c001/69de75a548ba4804bdbff89c9ca6764c/?a=1988&br=1626&bt=813&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020100617191201018903702204D96800&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=M3hxZ25meDY8dzMzMzczM0ApZjc5NDs7aGU6NzQ7Zjw4aWcuMy5mbWttNnJfLS1jMTRzc2AvYjRhLjExNGAvYjYuMjY6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=', optionsRequest, function (response) {
  response.pipe(file)
})
```

Comment: what is the error? do you have any logs? It is possible to initiate a HTTP request from Heroku to another server, that should be ok, but something else goes wrong (deploy?)

Comment: Simple not hapen.  The code follows normally, as if the file had been downloaded. However, when I try to send the file to Twitter, I can't find the file that was downlaoded And again, running locally I can download and send the file to Twitter

Comment: Ia there a way to see files in heroku live-time? See the video file that should be download for example

Comment: File system on Heroku is ephemeral, at every Dyno restart the files are wiped out. You should be able to write tmp files but Heroku doesnt make it easy to see/access those files. When you need to persist data they recommend to use a sort of storage

Comment: But the dyno is not being restarted (I think) as soon as the code to download the files runs, I call the function to send to Twitter, in the same js filée

Comment: I see, the file is probably somewhere but Heroku doesnt give any viewer or file system access. I would try to print the location of the file and to list the folders/files the app can access